# Formulating the Netwon Raphson

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, weighted-regression, weights, indicator-function

If this is the dataset under consideration and

```
    x1     x2     x3      y     weight
    1      0      1       0     1
    0      1      1       1     0.5
    1      1      1       1     0.5
    0      0      0       0     0.25
    0      1      0       0     0.25
    0      0      1       0     0.25
    0      1      0       0     0.25
    1      1      0       1     1
```

the likelihood is a binomial likelihood plus a $I{_j}$ term which represents an indicator function for the $j$ th sequence of $(x_1, x_2, x_2)$$(j=1,2...8)$ and $\gamma = (\gamma_1, \gamma_2.....\gamma_8)$ correspond to the weights where $∑{_{j=1}^8}\gamma_j =1$
$$l{(\theta \,X, y) } =∑ {_{i=1}^{N}y_i ((β_0+x^T_iβ)−ln(1+e^{(β_0+x^T_iβ)})}) + ∑ {_{i=1}^{N} ∑ {_{j=1}^{8} } I{_j}(x_i)ln( \gamma_j) }$$

How should I formulate my Newton Raphson for this likelihood which is a combination of a binomial model  plus some Indicator function representing the weights/probabilities of each row of data ? $
\begin{aligned}
\beta^\text{new} &= \beta^\text{old} + (X^{T}WX)^{-1}X^{T}(V)
\end{aligned}
$